# How can I continue the new value with the last number of the previous value in JSON?

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
with open('res.json', 'r') as file1:
    json_data = json.load(file1) 
for g in json_data['groups']:
  try:
   for i, group in enumerate(g['resources']):
     group['slot'] = i 

  except:
      continue


with open("RES_Edited.JSON", 'w') as json_edited:
     json.dump(json_data, json_edited, indent = 1)
```

It makes every slot like slot: 1, slot: 2, slot: 3 and that's great. But in the next child of g['resources'], it starts again like slot: 1, slot: 2, slot 3. I want it will continue from the last number of the previous child.
Like: slot: 4, slot: 5...

Thank you!

Comment: What is the json file structure

Comment: @SukumarRdjf https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LKrBjz-vg9WeYUEOyfI1b9T12MZ0ndzu

Answer (score 1):

Why not use one variable in your entire code rather than for a for loop like below:

```
with open('res.json', 'r') as file1:
    json_data = json.load(file1) 
i = 1
for g in json_data['groups']:
  try:
   for group in g['resources']:
     group['slot'] = i
     i += 1 

  except:
      continue

with open("RES_Edited.JSON", 'w') as json_edited:
     json.dump(json_data, json_edited, indent = 1)
```

Comment: I prefer Sukumar's solution. A lot more elegant.